# What the proper way to avoid console warning, when meteor collection is not ready

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze, meteor-collections

Every time I refresh the page I receive the following console warning for every single helper that is returning something to template from collection. I know the reason is because the subscription is not ready yet, but what is the solution?

**Exception in template helper: TypeError: Cannot read property 'x' of undefined.**

I'm already using `if(collection.find({}) !== undefined)` , but this makes my codes so messy, there must be a way to fix this issue. then I tried [guards](https://dweldon.silvrback.com/guards) and still not 100% solved.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Brendan's answer, using Blaze you can check if the subscriptions for the template is ready using

```
this.subscriptionsReady()
```

Which checks all the subscriptions scoped to the template with

```
this.subscribe()
```

in your `onCreated` or `onRendered` blocks

Comment: It's been a long time since I've used Blaze. Thanks for the follow-up!

Answer (score 1):

`Meteor.subscribe` returns a handle with a reactive method called `.ready()`. You can use that in your helper to only return the mongo cursor once it's ready.

Edit: [docs](http://docs.meteor.com/api/pubsub.html#Meteor-subscribe)